# react-native: image not show when not set width or height

Tags: reactjs, react-native

rn version : 0.38

just specify the image style using flex, no width and height, but Image will not show on mobile screen. How to do this.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri : 'https://www.baidu.com/img/bd_logo1.png'}}>
    </Image>
</View>



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  image: {
     flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
});
```

Comment: Try `image: {flex: 1, width: null, height: null}` for style.

Answer (score 7):

Network images require you to set height/width style props.

[React Native Documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#network-images).

> Many of the images you will display in your app will not be available
>   at compile time, or you will want to load some dynamically to keep the
>   binary size down. *Unlike with static resources, you will need to
>   manually specify the dimensions of your image.*

```
// GOOD
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />

// BAD
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} />
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. But how to realize Pinterest layout？1. how to get the parent element width not the window? 2. how to remove the blank space after using `resizeMode` to keep gallery？Thanks very much

Comment: You could use the [Dimensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) API to get the window height/width and manually calculate the image size based on how many rows/cells, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexGrow: 1` or `flex: 1` on your `Image` without specifying the size, but you will need to set the container `width` and `height` either using percentage or a fixed size:

```js
<View style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
  <Image
    source={{
      uri: "https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/logos_page/GitHub-Logo.png",
    }}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    resizeMode="contain"
  />
</View>
```

[checkout this snack example](https://snack.expo.dev/@bmartel/react-native-network-image-without-size)